# How to display loop by custom acf fields with pagination?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I ordered a service from a freelancer, he disappeared, now I'm trying to figure it out myself.
Please help me figure out what the problem might be.

He did loop and pagination by ACF custom field on the page. When the page loads, only pagination is displayed. not the field. When you click on any page switching button, the fields are displayed. Here is the link to the page
http://alex13746.beget.tech/klienty/
Here is the code

```
<div class="p-client">
        <div class="p-client__items">
          <?php
      

if( get_query_var('n') ) {
                  $page = $_GET['n'];
                } else {
                   $page = $_GET['n'];
                 
                }
        

// Variables
$row              = 0;
$images_per_page  = 9;
$images           = get_field( 'clients' );
$total            = count( $images );
$pages            = ceil( $total / $images_per_page );
$min              = ( ( $page * $images_per_page ) - $images_per_page ) + 1;
$max              = ( $min + $images_per_page ) - 1;




if( have_rows('clients') ):
  while ( have_rows('clients') ) : the_row();
    $row++;

    // Ignore this image if $row is lower than $min
    if($row < $min) { continue; }

    // Stop loop completely if $row is higher than $max
    if($row > $max) { break; } ?>  

    <div class="p-client__item">
     <div class="p-client__img">
      <img src="<?php $img=get_sub_field('img'); echo $img['url'];?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <p class="p-client__name"><?php the_sub_field('title');?></p>
  </div>
  
  <?php 
endwhile; ?>

<?php
endif;
?>
</div>

<div class="pagin_wrap" style="margin-left:15px;">
<?php
// Pagination
echo paginate_links( array(
  'base' => get_permalink() . '?n=%#%',
  'format' => '?n=%#%',
  'current' => $page,
  'total' => $pages
) ); ?>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The `else { $page = $_GET['n']; }` part doesn't make sense - that's the exact same thing, as in the `if` branch already. This should be just `else { $page = 1; }`, so that a default value is set, when no such parameter was passed via the URL.

Comment: Thanks! the fields are now displayed, but there is a new problem - pagination has stopped working.

Comment: Use of `get_query_var` is probably also wrong here (quote documentation, _"only retrieves public query variables that are recognized by WP_Query"_ - and that is not the case for `n`.) Try and replace that whole if/else block with just `$page = !empty($_GET['n']) ? (int)$_GET['n'] : 1;`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the problem!